# Setting treshold when using Mika Tuupola's Viewport Selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, viewport

I'm currently working in a portfolio site with horizontal navigation (http://espaun256.prompt-dev.com/moving/), and I'm using Mika Tuupola's Viewport Selectors (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport) to set the element closest to the center of the screen.

So far I have this:

```
$('#wrap').bind('scrollstop', function(){
    var inview = $('article.post:in-viewport').get().length,
        center = Math.round(inview/2)-1;

    $('article.post:in-viewport:eq('+center+')').addClass('activo');
});
```

Even if I'm close to get what I'm looking for, I know that there must be better and cleaner ways to do it...

... for example setting left and right screen tresholds using the same Viewport Selectors plugin ... any help figuring out how to set up tresholds would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok! so... I found this brilliant improvement of Mika Tuupola's Viewport Selectors here:
https://github.com/theluk/jquery_viewport/tree/d7ed501b5eac2bed90253c134df611cd2d843112
which adds the ability to pass the treshold as the selector parameter...

Thank you theluk[1](https://github.com/theluk) for the help.

So, I came to this:

```
$('#wrap').bind('scrollstop', function(){
    var inviewID = $('article.post:not(:left-of-screen('+ whatever-treshold +'))').attr('id');
    $('#'+inviewID).addClass('activo');
});
```

... and works so much better!